# Howto create knowledge base from Wiki, URL behind a login

Tags: azure-qna-maker

Need to create a knowledge base from a Wiki,however, the wiki is behind a login. What is the best way to feed a login protected URL into QnAmaker?

I've tried logging in in another tab on the same browser, but QnA maker simply shows the login content. I've quickly reviewed the QnA site howtos and searched stackoverflow. I'm sure folks have solved this issue but I haven't found any guidance.

If you have a link to online solutions, that would be wonderful.

Thanks...Steve

Answer (score 0):

QnAMaker uses a service on its own server to scrape FAQs, which is why you can't login yourself and then try to scrape.

If you're able to whitelist IP addresses so the QnAMaker service doesn't have to login, QnA Maker Management Service uses the following IP Ranges:

- West US: `13.91.0.0/16`
- East US: `52.191.0.0/18`

Otherwise, your FAQ would have to allow login via URL. If this is possible, it's likely something like:

- `http://username:password@example.com/`, or
- `http://myserver.com/~user=username&password=mypassword`

The other option would be to manually copy the site to [a supported file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/data-sources-supported) (like PDF or Doc) and then upload it.

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to the documentation where it specifies the IP ranges for the QnA Maker Management Service please.

Comment: There isn't documentation for it, but I do understand why you'd ask. I emailed the QnA devs. If you want, you can email me at my microsoft email in my profile and I can forward the email. I'd remove their email address, though. It's not meant to be public, but you'd at least see that the information came from my @microsoft email.